# Индекс вне границ массива C Sharp

Tags: c#, матрицы

надо вывести матрицу на екран, и возникла проблема в строке:

```
Console.Write(array[i,j]);
```

Индекс вылетает за пределы массива. в чем может быть проблема?

```
int[,] array = new int[5, 6] {
               {1987,2890 + 13, 3860,4216,4987, 4421},
               {5230,2984 - 13 ,4098 ,5633 ,2691 ,1673 },
               {2764,4290 - 13 ,3654 ,5139 ,4515 ,2116 },
               { 2993,3418 + 13 ,3218 ,4076 ,1374 ,2809},
               {3892 ,5000 + 13 ,3140 ,5880 ,3912 ,4367},
           };

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 6; i++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(array[i,j]);

                    }
                        Console.WriteLine();
                }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for (int j = 0; j < 6; **i++**)

Comment: Едрён батон, второй час голову ломаю, и не новичек вроде. Спасибо!

Comment: Да бывает... Лучше до метода внимательного всматривания не доводить, всё-таки исключение по делу было, и логирование индексов или отладка бы помогли.

Comment: Стараюсь избегать использовать подобные похожие по написанию переменные типа "i" и "j", ибо много подобных как у автора ошибок.